Open sea.testnet(sepolia)
I’ve recently launched a NFT contract on the sepolia testnet, and I’ve successfully connected my MetaMask account. However, the NFT token is not appearing on Opensea, it’s returning error [500] every time I try to refresh my tokens.
Anyone who can assist me?

Please provide more details with the block explorer link
You can try tracking whether your NFT is minted properly or not on Block Explorer
